# Have 240V at dryer 4 prong outlet, but get nP code

Tags: electrical

Dryer gets nP code meaning not enough current detected for heat sensor to activate to heat dryer. Is it the outlet or the dryer? 240V at outlet.

Comment: @Ruskes *4 prong outlet* means plug in. If it was hardwired, most people would have no idea how many wires and they certainly wouldn't call them "prongs".

Comment: Make/model of dryer? Picture of receptacle? Picture of panel showing breaker feeding the receptacle? Do you have a multimeter?

Comment: Is this a new problem? Or did you just install the dryer and it's having this problem?

Comment: Check your voltage carefully (120V from each hot to neutral doesn't necessarily mean 240V) ... and check your cord wiring. If 120V is across the right two wires. most dryer functions will work... but heat won't work.